# PyQt5 Mudando a ordem dos items adicionados dentro do QListWidget

Tags: python-3.x, gui

Olá eu queria saber se e possível  mudar a ordem de entradas dos items dentro do QListWidget, Atualmente quando eu insiro um novo item dentro do QListWidget ele e fixado no topo e os outros são jogado logo abaixo dele, queria fazer essa inversão do primeiro  sendo jogado para baixo e o ultimo fixado no topo.
Qual a melhor maneira de fazer isso? meu código está assim.

```
self.listWidget = QtWidgets.QListWidget(self.testPage)
self.listWidget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 10, 341, 341))
self.listWidget.setObjectName("listWidget")
self.listWidget.setStyleSheet("background-color:#000000;\n"
                                        "color:#ffffff;\n")


def loop_msg(self, username, msg):
    self.widget = QWidget()
    self.layout_main = QHBoxLayout()
    #--------------img--------------------
    self.iconQLabel = QtWidgets.QLabel()
    self.iconQLabel.setStyleSheet("background-color:#000000;")
    self.iconQLabel.setFixedSize(59,59)
    self.iconQLabel.setPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap("./img/v2.png"))

    self.layout_right = QVBoxLayout()
    self.layout_right_down = QHBoxLayout()  
    self.layout_right_down.addWidget(QLabel(msg))
    self.layout_main.addWidget(self.iconQLabel)
    self.layout_right.addLayout(self.layout_right_down) 
    self.layout_main.addLayout(self.layout_right)
    self.widget.setLayout(self.layout_main) 
    self.item = QListWidgetItem()
    self.item.setSizeHint(QSize(70, 70))
    self.listWidget.addItem(self.item)
    self.listWidget.addItem("   {}".format(username))
    self.listWidget.setItemWidget(self.item, self.widget)
```

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

É o comportamento esperado, conforme a documentação.

> https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlistwidget.html

Se não quer um ítem no final deve usar `insertItem` e não `addItem`.

```
self.listWidget.insertItem( 0, self.item)
```

Sendo que o 0 é a posição desejada.

Tem outras coisas estranhas no seu código (me parece que o loop está inserindo um label no layout e não um texto na lista, o que  parece uma péssima idéia). De qualquer forma, a lógica é a mesma, o layout também tem um `insert` no lugar do `add`.